# How do I find the inertia tensor of a tilted rectangular prism?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

Suppose you take a rectangular prism with:

- width: 10
- height: 10
- depth: 20
- the 10x10 face is facing in $x$ direction

and apply a yaw movement of $\theta$ degrees. How would you find the inertia tensor of the object with the yaw movement applied to it?

Comment: Why do you want to know the tensor in an “unnatural” coordinate system? With the simple form of the tensor oriented along the principal axes, you can calculate the moment of inertia around any axis.

Comment: @G.Smith what do you mean by that? I am not sure how this would be an unnatural coordinate system. Sorry if I am not getting obvious, I am new to this.

Comment: A natural/simple coordinate system for the inertia tensor is one in which it is diagonal. These axes are called principal axes. In the case of a symmetric object like a rectangular prism, these are the axes of symmetry. If you use a coordinate system in which the prism is tilted, the tensor will have off-diagonal components so it is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @G.Smith So does this mean that the inertia tensor of the tilted rectangular prism would be the same as the inertia tensor of a regular non titled rectangular prism?

Comment: No. If you use a coordinate system in which the prism is not tilted, the tensor will be diagonal. If you use a coordinate system in which the prism is tilted, the tensor will have nonzero off-diagonal components, and its diagonal components will be different from the non-tilted case.

Comment: @G.Smith that makes sense. So how would I about finding the inertia tensor of the tilted rectangular prism. For example, what if I wanted to tilt a solar panel on a satellite.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want the moment of inertia when tilting a cuboid around one of its edges (for which you don’t need a tilted coordinate system). If that’s correct, I’ll let someone provide an answer.